# toolbar hides others elements android kotlin

Tags: android, toolbar

I use Android Studio with Kotlin and I have a problem with my Toolbar, when I create it, it hides my others elements on my activity =>

**Without Toolbar**

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main))

    val user = User("Bob", 20)
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.go_to_second).setOnClickListener {
        println("Lancement de la seconde activité")
        val intent = Intent(this, Second::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("user", user)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.bouton_dialogue).setOnClickListener {
        val confdial = ConfirmDialog()
        confdial.listener = object: ConfirmDialog.ConfDeleteListener {
            override fun onPositiveClick() {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Recuperation du postive suppression dialog")
                val dd = FileListDialog()
                dd.show(supportFragmentManager, "onPositiveClick")
            }

            override fun onNegativeClick() {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Confirmation du negative suppression dialog")
            }

        }
        confdial.show(supportFragmentManager, "confirmDelete")
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/go_to_second"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="go pr l'aventure" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bouton_dialogue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="lancement dialogue" />
```

Result =>

[result without toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo62f.png)

**With Toolbar**

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val user = User("Bob", 20)
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.go_to_second).setOnClickListener {
        println("Lancement de la seconde activité")
        val intent = Intent(this, Second::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("user", user)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.bouton_dialogue).setOnClickListener {
        val confdial = ConfirmDialog()
        confdial.listener = object: ConfirmDialog.ConfDeleteListener {
            override fun onPositiveClick() {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Recuperation du postive suppression dialog")
                val dd = FileListDialog()
                dd.show(supportFragmentManager, "onPositiveClick")
            }

            override fun onNegativeClick() {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Confirmation du negative suppression dialog")
            }

        }
        confdial.show(supportFragmentManager, "confirmDelete")
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when(item?.itemId){
        R.id.action_second -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, Menu_activiy::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            return true
        }
        R.id.action_delete -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "supprimer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return true
        }
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/go_to_second"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="go pr l'aventure" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bouton_dialogue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="lancement dialogue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item android:id="@+id/action_second"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:title="Seconde"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:icon="@drawable/epee"
    android:title="Enregistrer"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/pioche"
    android:title="Supprimer"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/pomme"
    android:title="Aide"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Result with ToolBar =>

[Result with ToolBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6VEX.png)

So we can see ToolBar but others elements like "Hello World" TextView has disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Set the orientation of the LinearLayout:  
    `android:orientation="horizontal"` or     `android:orientation="vertical"`  
 also delete all the attributes that refer to `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Your toolbar's width is match_parent. This mean toolbar width is same your parent view. Your other views are still there but they are not visible, because  LinearLayout's orientation is horizontal. They are out of parent view (LinearLayout).

You must change your parent layouts orientation to vertical or change your parent views type.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the same which is stated in the above answer.

> When the orientation of a LinearLayout is unspecified, it is using the default, which is horizontal. Should the layout be a column or a row? Use "horizontal" for a row, "vertical" for a column. The default is horizontal.

Since you are not giving any orientation it's horizontal and pushing other views out of scope so you better give a orientation in your linear layout.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can margin your hello world textView with 
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"